# Создание похожего селектора.

Tags: css

Какой синтаксис?
Н-р я хочу создать селектор, который будет содержать все параметры другого селектора, плюс еще парочку

Например у меня есть `.whiteli` мне нужен селектор `secondwhiteli`

```
.whiteli
{
width: 150px;
height: 23px;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 200px;
 color: #459714;
 text-align: center;

}
.secondwhiteli
{
width: 150px;
height: 23px;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 400px;
 color: #459714;
 text-align: center;
}
```

В первом случае `left` был `400px`, во втором `200px`. Но в данном коде большая избыточность. Можно ли как-нибудь проще написать, чтобы второй селектор содержал в себе свойства второго + еще парочку свойств? 
Я бы просто второй класс создал, и одному элементу два класса привязал. Но одному элементу два класса задавать нельзя. Как вариант  можно конечно еще один блок див задать (обертку), таким образом решить проблему с двумя классами. Но думаю, есть метод попроще.

Comment: А с чем что мы сейчас должны сравнивать?

-----------

@Радик Камалов, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но одному элементу два класса задавать нельзя.

Вот, пожалуйста:

```
.red, .redAndBig {color:darkred}
.big, .redAndBig {font-size:200%; font-weight:bold}
```

Другими словами, в нашем примере мы ввели класс .redAndBig, который объединяет свойства классов .red и .big. Объединённый класс задаём в HTML таким образом:

```
<p class="redAndBig">Красный. И большой.</p>
```

Но спецификация CSS Level 2 позволяет задавать у элемента более одного класса. Для этого достаточно разделить названия классов пробелом:

```
<p class="red big">Красный. И большой.</p>
```